# ios10 prepareForSegue popoverPresentationController ObjC

Tags: objective-c, popover, ios10, uistoryboardsegue

I have UITableViewController in UINavigationController which I want to show in popover view and populate the fields in viewController.

Storyboard looks like the pic bellow. Left VC calls editIdeaSeque on navigation button press.

[image]

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editIdeaSegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        if (!isIpad) {
            EditIdeaTVC* edi = (EditIdeaTVC*)[nvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
            if (edi != nil)
                edi.editIdea = sender;
            }
        else {
            UINavigationController* nc = (UINavigationController*)[[segue.destinationViewController popoverPresentationController] presentedViewController];
            EditIdeaTVC* edi = (EditIdeaTVC*)[nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

            if (edi != nil)
                edi.editIdea = sender;
            }
    }
}
```

My prepare for segue works for iphone which is similar storyboard layout. Ipad part crashes cause edi is some garbage pointer.

```
-[EditIssueTVC setEditIdea:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157d6c7a0
```

I was expecting that presentedViewController will be UINavigationController ...

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationController* nc = (UINavigationController*)[[segue.destinationViewController popoverPresentationController] presentedViewController];
```

You're over-thinking this. The navigation controller *is* the destination view controller. The situation is identical to your earlier code:

```
UINavigationController *nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
```

There is nothing about the popover situation that would change what view controller is at the far end of the destination arrow.

Comment: Well, that was the first thing I tried and saw that app was crashing, so I started to dig into popoverPresentationController thing ..

Comment: What I'm saying is: delete the whole iPad check. The whole point is that this thing will behave automatically on both iPhone and iPad. A segue is a segue. A destination is a destination. Your code will work the same on both types of device without any check.